# Вывод форматированных ошибок в браузере(PHP + Xdebug)

Tags: php

Ребята, подскажите как вывести в браузер [отформатированные](https://xdebug.org/docs/develop#stack_trace) ошибки - оранжевая такая табличка, а не просто текст из которого приходится все высматривать тратя время.
Из того что нашел и пробовал:

```
    html_errors=Off //в php.ini поменял - не сработало

    ini_set('xdebug.auto_trace', 1) //не сработало, так же добавлял в php.ini
```

секция из php.ini

```
    zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
    xdebug.mode = debug
    xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

связка nginx + php-fpm7.4

Answer (score 0):

В начале файла напишите:

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
```

В качестве дополнения, если надо что-то конкретное выводить, то вот есть варианты:

```php
// Выключение протоколирования ошибок
error_reporting(0);

// Включать в отчёт простые описания ошибок
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Включать в отчёт E_NOTICE сообщения (добавятся сообщения о
// непроинициализированных переменных или ошибках в именах переменных)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Добавлять сообщения обо всех ошибках, кроме E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// Добавлять в отчёт все ошибки PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Добавлять в отчёт все ошибки PHP
error_reporting(-1);

// То же, что и error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Comment: Да ошибки то отображаются, я имею в виду их внешний вид как https://xdebug.org/docs/develop#stack_trace , у меня же они выводятся "голыми"

Comment: Покажите, а то не понятно. У меня по дефолту отображается

Comment: сейчас ошибки и вывод var_dump выглядят вот так: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ua_9d4uyG9qmZ7LXxXB1yrt-xK9G2dR7/view?usp=sharing  хотелось бы получить вот такой результат: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sD7gLlHiQ2kDLwQLUMzjY00aqnZle7YS/view?usp=sharing  только, что нашел в доке по ексдибагу, что нужно сменить xdebug.mode на debug, вот только в VS Code перестает соответственно работать "прослушка" и точки останова не фурычат... Интересно, можно ли как нибудь объединить вывод ошибок в таком стиле и дебаггинг в VS code

Comment: @MaxOstepan Нельзя, вы либо делаете вывод человеко-читаемым, либо делаете вывод машино-читаемым. Теги форматирования не дают программам распарсить состояние

Comment: @MaxOstepan Но вы можете вручную вставить теги форматирования... Но для этого будут нужны навыки работы с регулярными выражениями, либо использовать [Prism.js](https://prismjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Меняем строку:

```
xdebug.mode = debug
```

на:

```
xdebug.mode = develop
```

Единственно, что перестаёт работать - отладка в IDE.